# Change prefix icon color of text form field in flutter on clicking the field

Tags: flutter

I have a name form field in flutter app. There's a prefix icon in it. When I click the form field the color of icon changes to blue, rather I want to change it to green. How can I do that, can anyone please guide me? This is its code :

```
 TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
       
        hintText: "Name",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter's way to go is to use resolveWith. You can check the current state to check if the text field is focused, shows an error, etc. And depending on that you set the color.

From the docs (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html):

```
final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Theme(
      data: themeData.copyWith(
          inputDecorationTheme: themeData.inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
        prefixIconColor:
            MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
            return Colors.green;
          }
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
            return Colors.red;
          }
          return Colors.grey;
        }),
      )),
      child: TextFormField(
        initialValue: 'abc',
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Theme` color to change then define the focus node to determine when the field is on focus in order to apply these color changes

```
... 
  FocusNode _fieldNode = FocusNode(); //<-Define this then
...
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person,
            color: _fieldNode.hasFocus
                ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                : Colors.purple)),
       
        hintText: "Name",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I did this but it didn't work

Comment: Check my updated code:

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default color for selection such as textfield border or prefix icon of the same using `colorScheme`

```
MaterialApp(theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(primary: kPrimaryColor),
 )
```